# Web Crawling using Curl in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I'm new to web development. I'm creating a web crawler using curl in php.

I should be able to access the specific data from another site in my site. And it should not redirect to the url which i'm giving as input. I should access it in my site itself. Lets say for example, I want to extract specific data from this page  https://shop.vodafone.in/shop/rechargeOffers.jsp
ie View All Recharge->Bonus Card->Details->the data in details pop up window.

How can i achieve it?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$url="https://shop.vodafone.in/";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
//curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
$data = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
// you can do something with $data like explode(); or a preg match regex to get the exact information you need
echo $data;
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use [`Domdocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) library or you can also use [`pQuery`](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) that is provide selectors like jQuery

Answer (score 0):

use the symfony dom crawler: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html

you can install it with composer or download it.

simple example from the docs:

```
<?php

   use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

   $html = <<<'HTML'
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
        <body>
           <p class="message">Hello World!</p>
           <p>Hello Crawler!</p>
        </body>
    </html>
    HTML;

    $crawler = new Crawler($html);

    foreach ($crawler as $domElement) {
       print $domElement->nodeName;
    }

    //or something like this
    $crawler = $crawler->filter('body > p');
```